# Convert InputStream into Stream<String> given a Charset

Tags: java, io, stream, java-8, java-stream

I want to convert an `InputStream is` into a `Stream<String> stream` given a `Charset cs` in such a way that `stream` consists of the lines of `is`. Furthermore a line of `is` should not be read immediately but only in case `stream` needs it.

Comment: And what have you tried? Questions should show effort by including an attempt or research

Comment: Does it have to be `InputStream`? If you are going to read files then you could use `Files.lines(Path path, Charset cs)`. You can take a look at source code of this method to figure out your solution.

Comment: In my case it is the InputStream coming from `HttpURLConnection#getInputStream()`.

Comment: Okay, I did so. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30336889/convert-inputstream-into-streamstring-of-strings-of-fixed-length

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I think you can try:

```
Stream<String> lines = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, cs)).lines();
```

Comment: Is there a way to auto disconnect the HttpURLConnection after the complete InputStream was read?

Comment: You can read the stream in a `try-with-resources` statement and possibly add a `finally` block that calls `disconnect()` on the `HttpURLConnection` object: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#disconnect()

Comment: `try( BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, cs)); Stream<String> lines=br.lines() ) { /* your stream operation */ }` will do.

Comment: In case you need more flexibility defining the pattern this is also nice: new Scanner(is).findAll(<pattern>)

Comment: Apache Commons IO has an `AutoCloseInputStream` that automatically closes the stream when it reaches the end. You can then safely return this `Stream` without having to wrap it in a try-with-resources. e.g. `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new AutoCloseInputStream(is), cs)).lines()` (FYI @principal-ideal-domain, if you still need this info 7 years on...)

Comment: I don't like `BufferedReader`. Is there any way to make a `Path` object out of an inputstream (e.g. `System.in`) so that I can type something like `Files.lines(InputStreamPathObject, charset)`?