# How to access static files from a test class in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, static-files

I have a similar question to [this guy who was trying to load a static file in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33314388/how-to-access-images-from-a-resource-folder-in-intellij-idea-without-having-to-g) but the difference is that I'm trying to load that static file *from a test class* and am unclear how to do it.

My project hierarchy in IntelliJ looks like this:

```
projectroot
  .idea
  src
    main
      java
        net.joeclark.mypackage
          MyClass.java
      resources
        data.txt
    test
      java
        net.joeclark.mypackage
          MyClassTest.java
```

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Community 2019.1.  I want to write a test in MyClassTest.java which calls on the data in the file `data.txt`.  The `resources` directory is "marked" as the "Test Resources Root" and I am trying to open the file from MyClassTest.java like so:

```
@Test
void canDoSomethingWithTheFile() {
    String fileName = "data.txt";
    try(Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
        // do something with the file
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

However, running the project in IntelliJ throws a NoSuchFileException.

I have tried variations on the filename like "`/data.txt`" and "`./data.txt`" and I have tried putting the file in a package directory structure under `resources`, i.e. "`resources/net/joeclark/mypackage`" and get the same issue.

Inspecting the `target` directory I find that the static file has been deposited under `classes` rather than `test-classes`, as you see here:

```
  target
    classes
      net.joeclark.mypackage
        MyClass.class
      data.txt
    test-classes
      net.joeclark.mypackage
        MyClassTest.class
```

I don't know if that's the cause of my problem or not.  How do I solve it?  How can I open that static file in my test class?

## Edit: not a duplicate question

The suggested duplicate is helpful, but (1) its accepted answer doesn't answer my question or *its* question (the highest-voted alternative is closer to the mark), and (2) it doesn't address either the "why" of what's happening, or the best practice to correct it.

## What I would put in an answer, if allowed

I have discovered that the test seems to run with a working directory of "projectroot" for the *source* files, not the "target" or output directory, so if I use the path "src/main/resources/data.txt" I do reach the file.  A better explanation of *why* that occurs would be helpful. (i.e., why does the *compiled* test class refer to the file in the *source* directories?).

I have also discovered that having `resources` in the `main` directory is less than a best practice, because that causes the test data file to be packaged with the .jar.  By moving the `resources` directory under `test` I can run my test successfully (using "src/test/resources/data.txt") but the resource doesn't get packaged along with the compiled code.

## Edit 2: A second way using ClassReader

Mark's comment suggested using `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/data.txt")`. This produces an InputStream, but I didn't get any guidance on how to convert that into a Stream. Drawing on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30336257/convert-inputstream-into-streamstring-given-a-charset) I came up with the following, which works:

```
    try(Stream<String> stream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/data.txt"))).lines()) {
        // do the thing with the file;
    } catch (NullPointerException e) { // note, not the same exception type
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Look at these question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28673651/how-to-get-the-path-of-src-test-resources-directory-in-junit.

Comment: in that directory layout you need to use `src/resources/data.txt` as filename.

Comment: @Ivan that didnt work but `src/main/resources/data.txt` worked. Frankly, I don't understand why.

Comment: You shouldn't access it as a file, but using `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/data.txt")`

Comment: @MarkRotteveel that's probably a best practice, but being new to Java I literally wanted to test whether I knew how to write code that would allow it to ingest a file.  I already have working tests with mock data.

Comment: Resources aren't necessarily available as files on the filesystem (eg when packaged in a jar). If you want to use a file, by all means do that, but then you shouldn't define it as a resource. And you should either use an absolute path or the correct relative path (the path needs to be relative to the current working directory, which - when run from an IDE - is usually the root of your project).